# Interpretation of electromagnetic energy density and poyting vectors

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, field-theory

All that follows is in natural units and in free space.

In Feynman's lecture on physics, volume II chapter 27, Feynman derives the electromagnetic energy density $u = \frac 1 2 \left( \lVert \bf E \rVert^2 + \lVert \bf B \rVert^2 \right)$ and energy density flux $\bf S = \bf E \times \bf B$, by stating that we are looking for $u$ and $\bf S$ such that the following equation holds :

$$\frac {\partial u} {\partial t} + \nabla\cdot\bf S = - \bf E \cdot j.$$

We are *defining* energy density and flux of the fields such that this equation holds. Then, he does some magic algebra to find combination of $\bf E$ and $\bf B$ that satisfies the above equation.

This would be a sufficient definition if there was a unique solution, but he then tells us:

> There are, in fact, an infinite number of different possibilities for $u$ and $\bf S$, and so far no one has thought of an experimental way to tell which one is right!

As I see in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/562563/standard-formula-for-energy-density-of-electromagnetic-field), it's still the case that no experiment other than gravitational effect of the energy of light could decide what should be the correct form of $u$ and $\bf S$.

There are, apparently, other more theoretical arguments that justify this choice over some other choice, but in light that no actual observable difference (appart from the extremely weak gravitational effect) are implied by the choice of solution of $u$ and $\bf S$ as solution to the above equation, I'm asking how much reality we should grant to the electromagnetic field energy density and Poynting vector, especially on the interpretation of where the energy is flowing in an electric circuit.

For example, the Poynting vector in a charging capacitor is pointing inward from the outside, which is quite counterintuitive. As $u$ and $\bf S$ are somewhat arbitrary as far as day to day life is concerned (that is, if we exclude gravity), does this mean that we should only view them as mathematical artifacts that just happen to give us the work done on a charge when we compute their integral, or is their any reason why we should view them as ‘real’ and that energy is ‘really’ flowing from outside space into the capacitor?

Answer (score 0):

In one sentence, you should grant the same *reality* to EM energy *density* or to the Poynting vector as you would grant to electrostatic voltage (potential) or to the magnetic vector potential. For EM energy only the full volume integral is meaningful or for the Poynting vector when its integral is taken over a closed surface. These are directly measurable quantities and related to the work done, just as the contour integral of the vector potential is equal the flux or the difference between two points gives you the voltage drop, both are directly measurable. Since their integrals are all well-defined and represent work or some such you do not ever get into contradiction with either physics or mathematics.

The Poynting vector can be even more troubling than what bothers you here for you can have a static $E$ and a static $H$ field and then there is an apparent $S=E \times H$ energy transport. Of course, if you calculate what goes in and out of a closed surface you will see that nothing is going anywhere.

Comment: In static, electric potential is only defined up to a constant, so I would say the geometry of V tells you a lot about the situation. You can add pretty much any vector field to the Poynting vector as long as you subtract the divergence of its time integral to the energy density. There geometry of electric potential seems much more restricted than that of $u$ and $\bf S$, and I would thus think that $V$ tells you more about the geometry of the situation than the precise value of $\bf S$ or $u$ at each point.