# Why is calculating the resulting field from polarization not recursive?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

In a parallel-plate capacitor filled with a dielectric, if the plates are kept at a potential $V$, and the dielectric has some (non-linear) polarization $P$ that is dependent on the magnitude of $E$ (so $P$ is a vector of which the magnitude is some function of $E$, for simplicity sake we can say it is in the direction of $E$), then the electric field applied to the space within the plates is $E = V/d$.

Then, from this the E-field inside the dielectric can be calculated, which opposes this applied $E$ field.

However, what I don't understand is, why is this not done recursively? Why is the resulting $E$ field not the one that again determines the polarization, which then again determines the dipole moments and thus how the E-field inside the dielectric behaves? Like finding an equilibrium?
But in all exercises on this it is just done naively, once. I don't understand this physically.

Comment: Well, one way to look at it is that you can perform the infinite sum and set the total difference to be the polarisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. It is not "recursive" because in the equation
$$\mathbf D= \epsilon_0 \mathbf E + \mathbf P \tag{1}\label{1}$$ and in the constitutive equation $$\mathbf P = \mathbf P(\mathbf E)\tag{2}\label{2}$$ the field $\mathbf E$ is defined to be the *end-result* of the implicit recursion you are alluding to. In other words, it implies an electrostatic & thermodynamic equilibrium that has been established after all the dipoles will have aligned properly so that the *macroscopic* fields $\mathbf {\{D, E, P\}}$ so that $\eqref {1}$ and $\eqref{2}$ are satisfied along with all the macroscopic boundary conditions. Note that the microscopic field of which there is only one, say $\mathfrak E$,  with $\mathbf E$ being the macroscopic average of $\mathfrak E$, satisfying the Maxwell equations $\nabla \times \mathfrak E = 0$ and $\nabla \cdot \mathfrak E = \rho/\epsilon_0$ everywhere, does not have to satisfy the macroscopic boundary conditions on the dielectric, such as the continuity of $\mathfrak E_t$ or $\mathfrak E_n$.

When calculating the energy/work relationship in electrostatics it is "derived" that spatial energy density is $\mathbf E \cdot d \mathbf D$. In fact, this is not the *internal energy* but rather the (Helmholtz) *free energy* at some temperature where the temperature dependence is expressed in the temperature dependent constitutive relationship $\mathbf P = \mathbf P(\mathbf E, T)$ because it is related to the infinitesimal isothermal work needed to create and maintain the electrostatic configuration. Actually it is better to consider the full volume integral $\delta w =\int_{\infty} dV \mathbf E \cdot \delta \mathbf D$ as being representative of that work as the amount it takes to change the displacement vector field by $\delta \mathbf D$. Interestingly and significantly, using some standard vector analytical identities this integral taken over all space can be transformed to another one $$\delta w  = \delta \frac{1}{2}\int_{\infty} dV \mathbf E_0^2  - \int_{\mathcal V}dV\mathbf P \cdot \delta  \mathbf E_0  \tag{3}\label{3}$$ where $\mathcal V$ is the space occupied by the dielectric and $\mathbf E_0$ is the *vacuum* field without the dielectric, and in this form $\delta w$ is the electrostatic work it takes to maintain the sources (free charges) of $\mathbf E_0$ to be the *same* amount at the *same* places as it was before the dielectric was inserted.

Comment: Thanks, this answer elucidates the matter, and surprises me. I have used a wrong interpretation where the E in P(E) is the vacuum field.

Comment: If you have a vacuum energy like E = V/d, because two plates are put at potential diff V at distance d, and I know the formula for polarization P(E), how then do I have to calculate the E field?

Comment: Many years ago I made the same mistake as the one you are alluding to, specifically, in the magnetic case ( H v. E and B v. D). While nowadays this issue is better discussed in most books it is rare to find a fully detailed  analysis of it. Probably the first ones are in Stratton or Guggenheim or Heine but few read those, see similar discussion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/761230/find-work-given-an-equation-of-state/761257#761257) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/562563/standard-formula-for-energy-density-of-electromagnetic-field/562629#562629)

Comment: If it is a "simple" material then there is a local *macroscopic* relationship between the field $E$ and the induced polarization $P$. The relationship *can* be linear (e.g., glass) and then there is a susceptibility coefficient $\chi = \chi (E)$, or relative permittivity $\epsilon_r = 1+ \chi$, that gives you P (or D). So the question is how to get $E$ from $E_0$? That is quite complicated problem unless the geometry is simple. The parallel plate capacitor with negligible fringing field has a *simple* geometry where you can make the assumption that $E\approx E_0 = V/d$ and then $P = \chi V/d$.

Comment: In my example, it is not simple, P(E) has a relationship that has a term E^2 (where E is the magnitude of the E field) inside it, and also a multiplication with the E vector (because it follows the field) - which means it is of the order E^3. So I'm assuming to calculate this, you need to integrate, but I'm rather surprised by the complexity - I also sent the professor this thread.

Comment: So it is a *nonlinear* dielectric $P=\chi(E)E$ with $\chi = \chi_0 + \chi_2 E^2+....$. As long as the *geometry* is simple, such as a parallel plate condenser with negligible fringing fields, you can still write $E \approx  E_0 = V/d$.

Answer (score 0):

When puzzling over problems like this, you should always consider how you would do the experiment. Here, the dielectric constant is a parameter you measure by making a capacitor and determining the polarization by measuring the capacitance. So, the experiment finds the equilibrium you seek.

Comment: I'll update the question because the polarization is a formula and I'm looking for a theoretical solution, not an experimental one.

Comment: @buddhabrot Physics is not mathematics. Every physical question is fundamentally about the results of experiments and observations. Polarization is a theoretical model crafted to match experimental results.